# How to enable puppet agent retrieve manifest settings from master

Tags: puppet

I am running puppet master on sys A, and puppet agent on sys B.

I would like to have agent retrieve manifest changes as and when it changes and then get those changes applied without me manually issuing `puppet agent --test` command on agent.

How can I cater to this use case?

Thanks in advance
Ramesh

Comment: Please indicate what research you have done yourself and why you could not resolve this issue on your own.

Comment: I found that there is "runinterval" param that can be added to puppet.conf file under agent section to set how frequently I need puppet agent to apply settings.

Comment: However, not able to find a way to automatically trigger puppet agent apply settings whenever change happens to manifest on master side

Answer (score 2):

The typical way of triggering the `agent` is [mco](https://puppetlabs.com/mcollective).

You will either want to

- hook that into your version control system or, failing that
- employ `inotify` or a similar monitor

but the former is preferable.

Comment: Thanks Felix.... currently we don't have bandwidth to try out mcollective... can you please suggest if there is an alternative way?

Comment: @RameshMohanReddy As a stopgap, you can try `puppet kick` while you're [still running Puppet 3.x](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3.7/reference/deprecated_command.html#now).

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for orchestration tool, CI/CD tools, such as `mco`, `rundeck`, `bamboo`, `jenkins` etc.

If you disable "puppet agent -t" on puppet clients to run every half hour (the default setting), then you need one of these orchestration tools to delivery puppet changes to puppet master, if the delivery is successful, then automatically trigger the command `puppet agent -t` running on nominated puppet agents.